# How can I get autocomplete arguments before ENTER?

Tags: python, autocomplete, hook

There is a file `argComp.py` in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I install [argcomplete 1.0.0](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/argcomplete/1.0.0) module successfully.

```
chmod +x argComp.py
```

and then

```
data = [ name1 : { address1 : [Korea, Seoul ] }, name2 : { address2 : [ USA, LA ] } ]

./argComp.py --name [tab]

./argComp.py --name
name1 name2

./argComp.py --name name1 --address [tab]
Korea Seoul
```

I want read the my argument by realtime before the user presses <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. For this, the argcomplete module should read text *name*  in `--name name1`, and then check data by `name1`.

I could I get data and make the --address list ?

I want to implement this concept to file browser realtime..

Please help, and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit difficult to understand what you're asking but I think this might be what you want:

`Argcomplete` only work when you use [argparse](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html) to manage your command line arguments.

For your example `argComp.py` should be something like this

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# PYTHON_ARGCOMPLETE_OK
import argcomplete, argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Test passing arguments')
parser.add_argument('--name1', metavar='NAME1', nargs=1, choices=['Korea', 'Seoul'], help="First address line")
parser.add_argument('--name2', metavar='NAME2', nargs=1, choices=['USA', 'LA'], help="Second address line")

argcomplete.autocomplete(parser)
args = parser.parse_args()

# Your code here
# Print the arguments
print(args.name1[0],"-",args.name2[0])
```

You can run `argComp.py` by typing

```
python argComp.py --name1 Korea --name2 LA
```

To print usage details

```
python argComp.py -h
```

---

If you want it to be fully dynamic you can store your arguments in `json` format then pass it as environment variable

lets say that we want to parse the following data (json format)

```
'{"name1": {"address": ["korea", "Seoul"], "gender": ["Male","Female"]}, "name2": {"address": ["USA", "LA"]} }'
```

then we will store it in an environment variable, lets name it `PY_ARGS`
so in the terminal:

```
$ PY_ARGS='{"name1": {"address": ["korea", "Seoul"], "gender": ["Male","Female"]}, "name2": {"address": ["USA", "LA"]} }'
$ export PY_ARGS
```

Of course you can set this environment variable from any place you want i.e. another program.

Now our program `argComp.py` will be

```
import argcomplete, argparse
import os
import json

args = os.environ['PY_ARGS'] # get the environment variable

# Parse env variable to dictionary
args_dict = json.loads(args)

# create the top-level parser
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest='subparser')

# Get keys as list
top_level_keys = list(args_dict.keys()) # [name1, name2]

for i in range(0,len(top_level_keys)):
    key = top_level_keys[i] # when i=0 name1
    sub_dict = args_dict[key] # when i=0 {"address": ["korea", "Seoul"], "gender": ["Male","Female"]}
    sub_parser = subparsers.add_parser(key)
    sub_level_keys = list(sub_dict.keys()) # when i=0 [address, gender]

    for k in range(0, len(sub_level_keys)):
        sub_key = sub_level_keys[k] # when k=0 address
        choices = sub_dict[sub_key] # when k=0 [korea, Seoul]
        sub_parser.add_argument('--'+sub_key, nargs=1, choices=choices)


argcomplete.autocomplete(parser)
args = parser.parse_args()

# Your code here
print(args)
```

Now we can run `argComp.py`

```
$ ./argComp.py name1 --gender Male
Namespace(address=None, gender=['Male'], subparser='name1')
```

Or with address

```
$ ./argComp.py name1 --gender Male --address korea
Namespace(address=['korea'], gender=['Male'], subparser='name1')
```

This will print error

```
$ ./argComp.py name2 --gender Male --address korea
usage: argComp.py name2 [-h] [--address {USA,LA}]
argcomplete2.py name2: error: argument --address: invalid choice: 'korea' (choose from 'USA', 'LA')
```

help is nicely printed

```
$ ./argComp.py -h
usage: argComp.py [-h] {name1,name2} ...

positional arguments:
  {name1,name2}

optional arguments:
  -h, --help     show this help message and exit
```

and

```
$ ./argComp.py name1 -h
usage: argComp.py name1 [-h] [--gender {Male,Female}]
                             [--address {korea,Seoul}]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --gender {Male,Female}
  --address {korea,Seoul}
```

The trick here is to create dictionary from your json string and add [subparser(s)](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/argparse.html#sub-commands).

You can add more sub levels to match your needed arguments structure.

Comment: Thank you.. But I mean if there is no data set. How could I get the argument  in buffer and use this argument for checking data realtime I press [TAB] before I [ENTER]... Your example is absolute path. My data set is just example..

Comment: @HyunjunCheong check my edit. I think this is what you want